# regular expression: quotes within quotes

Tags: java, regex

I need to do following type of regular expression match

E.g if i have a string  -  `some "This is "sample" data" example`

I want to extract **"This is "sample" data"** out of the above string. Could please give me a regular expression which can return me desired results

**More Details**

I have a string as - `keyword = "This is "blood" sample" AND name = "some text"`.
 I need to extract 
keyword = "This is "blood" sample"
name = "some text"
out of it as two separate strings.

Could you please suggest a regular expression for this kind of thing

I used `(keywords|name|title) = (.*?(\\\".*\\\").*?)` as regular expression and it does not work as expected. It returns me the whole string as it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Which tool are you using to do the extraction? Details of dealing with things such as quotes can differ from tool to tool.
2) Are you wanting to match that string exactly, or any quoted data that contains other quoted data? I.e., would you want to match "a "b" c"?

Comment: So is the group you are interested in enclosed by a pair of double quotation marks? And can double quotation marks be inside this group?

Comment: Could you provide a few more examples? Both of correct, and incorrect matches.

Comment: If this is your only requirement, maybe it would be easier to just walk the String.

Comment: You can only decide by context, what is an inner comment: `"Come here!" he said, while she said "Stay away!"` You see, there are two separate quotes, not an outer and an inner one. How shall an algorithm decide?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you're after, so I'll fill in the gaps by guessing.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\\".*\\\").*?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("some \"This is \"sample\" data\" example");

if (m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

**Output:**

```
"This is "sample" data"
```

---

Some remarks:

- What should be matched in `a b "c d "e f "g h" i j" k l" m n`?
- What should be matched in `a "b" c"`?
- If you want to treat `"` and `"` as opening and closing parenthesis, regular expressions are not for you.

Comment: why do we need 3 backslashes? i'm working on similar problems and i thought 2 is what we need

Comment: The third backslash is to avoid having the `"` terminate the string literal.